# Is an HTML 5 Article tag appropriate for general website documents

Tags: html, article

Is the `<article>` tag an appropriate wrapper for site documents, such as "Terms", "Cookie Policy" and "Privacy"?  Or should it be reserved for proper articles, such as blogs posts?

Comment: As you say, it is subjective, so the question is primarily opinion-based. Moreover, the choice hardly has any practical implications; it’s just a coding style question.

Comment: I don't think this is "too subjective" in the sense that it needs to be closed.  It's asking for the intended, semantic uses-case for the article tag in HTML5.

Comment: Read the specs, it is pretty clear. Any selfcontained, like a disclaimer would be approriate to use a article tag for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The W3 Spec on the `<article>` tag

According to [the W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element):

> The article element represents a complete, or self-contained,
>   composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in
>   principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in
>   syndication.

It then goes on to list some example use-cases for the `<article>` tag:

> This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper
>   article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget
>   or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

### Your specific use-case

All that being said, I don't think the tag is really appropriate for wrapping your "terms of service" / "privacy" statements.  While those could loosley fit under "any other independent item of content", I don't really think those items conform to the semantics of "a composition that is independently distributable."

Those types of things are very specific to your site, so I would say they don't fit the purpose of the article tag.

Here's a really good blog post on the HTML 5 article tag that I read: [The article element](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element

Here is a quote "The article element represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content."

Answer (score -1):

Article elements are *sectioning* content ("section" = "part of"). So you shouldn't ever need them to wrap a whole document, regardless of what the content of the document is about.

The appropriate wrapping element for a whole document less the metadata is `<body>`. The primary text of the document after removing banners, sidebars and footers etc., may be wrapped in a `<main>` element.